# How to manage actor shutdown in a singleton ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a singleton actor system in my application, and this works perfectly fine except that when the same application is loaded and unloaded inside the same JVM for testing, I have an error because I try, in my startup procedure, to recreate an actor which already exists.

As a result I get an `akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException` because the Actor name is not unique.

I am looking for a way to smoothly shutdown the actors depending on the actor systems without shutting down the actor system itself. Which is a reasonable strategy for that?

Comment: Have you checked out http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html#Stopping_actors ?

Comment: This requires you to keep track of all the actors for that system. I was looking for an automatic solution

Comment: Well, not really. Because of Akka's hierarchical organization you need to keep track only of the top level actors, which I'm guessing are few in number.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly answer to your question - "*...  a way to smoothly shutdown the actors ...*", but you mentioned that you are able to able to start two applicatons in same JVM.

Could you make your actor system to be *singleton within application instance* instead of singleton within whole JVM?

You would have two independent actor systems, you won't have name conflicts and won't have to start/stop specific actors.

I guess problems could be if some of actors are interacting with outside world, for example consuming some messages from JMS etc. Then it would not be obvious which actor system is processing them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want somethings like this ?

```
object AkkaTest extends App {
  import akka.actor._
  import akka.pattern.ask
  import akka.util.Timeout
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  val system = ActorSystem.create

  val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props[MasterOfPuppets], name = "masterOfPuppets")

  private object AllTerminated

  private class MasterOfPuppets extends Actor {

    var supervised = 0

    var waiterForTerminated: Option[ActorRef] = None

    def receive = {
      case actor: ActorRef =>
        context.watch(actor)
        supervised += 1
      case Terminated(dead) =>
        supervised -= 1
        if (supervised == 0) {
          waiterForTerminated.map(_ ! AllTerminated)
          waiterForTerminated = None
        }
      case AllTerminated =>
        if (supervised == 0) {
          sender ! AllTerminated
        } else {
          waiterForTerminated = Some(sender)
        }
    }
  }

  private class TestedActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case a: Any => sender ! a
    }
  }

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds) // needed for `?` below

  // Create first actor
  val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[TestedActor], name = "name1")
  supervisor ! actor1
  actor1 ! PoisonPill

  val waitForIt = supervisor ? AllTerminated
  Await.result(waitForIt, 5.seconds)
  // Same name
  val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[TestedActor], name = "name1")
  supervisor ! actor2

  println("ok then")
}
```

Your problem is very simple : Akka and message are asynchronous. If you try to create an actor just after you kill him, the name is not available.
Try just a Thread.sleep before creating new actor and it will work.. :)

Comment: Nooo, you don't sleep. you use Death Watch and create the new actor once you get the Terminated-message.